# Add low stock notice to Woocommerce products but quantity based on each products low stock settings

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I searched on stack overflow and found code for creating a low stock notice on the WooCommerce product pages, the only problem is that this code only works on a global out of stock total of 10.  I need to create a notice for each simple and variable product based on that specific products availability settings.  Some products will be low on stock when we have 10 left other products will be low on stock when we have 25 left.
Can somebody help with code to show notice on product based on each products or variations low stock levels?

```
`add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','get_stock_variations_from_product', 10);

function get_stock_variations_from_product(){
    global $product;
    if( $product->get_type() == 'simple' ){
        if( $product->get_stock_quantity() > 0 && $product->get_stock_quantity() < 10 ){
            echo '<div class="leftstock">Only '. $product->get_stock_quantity() . ' left in stock!</div>';
        }
    }else if( $product->get_type() == 'variable' ){
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        foreach($variations as $variation){
            if( isset( $variation['max_qty'] ) ){
                $attr_string = [];
                foreach ( $variation['attributes'] as $attr_name => $attr_value ) {
                    $attr_string[] = $attr_value;
                }
                if( $variation['max_qty'] > 0 && $variation['max_qty'] < 10 ){
                    echo '<div class="leftstock">'.implode( ', ', $attr_string ).' - Only '.$variation['max_qty'] . ' left in stock!</div>';
                }else if( $variation['max_qty'] < 1 ){
                    echo '<div class="leftstock">'.implode( ', ', $attr_string ).' - Out of stock!</div>';
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to add some settings on the product backend, for simple and variable products (and for variations too, I think): You can get inspiration [from those threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_product_options_stock_fields) and for variations [those other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_variation_options_inventory)